# Asking to find the documentation of the GPS NMEA sentence$GNACCURACY

Tags: gps, android-gps

I am developing an app using the GPS and looking at the sentences receved by may smartphone I see this sentence I did not see before:

17:27:07,$GNACCURACY,2.4,179.9,2.1,20.8*2D

I see one of it every second or every couple of seconds. I search the web to find its description but I was not able to find any helpful documentation.
If someone has a datasheet, product manual or every else describing the format, purpose and anything else  would be very happy to read it.
Thanks,
Massimo